# Swift Hide Back Button on Navigation Controller or Better Way?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm creating a Swift application and I'm still getting used to Xcode and iOS best practices. I have an initial view controller that allows users to login with facebook, and then I have a registration navigation controller that is opened if the facebook login is successful. The issue is that I don't want a back button to be available in the navigation of my registration controller and after a user successfully registers, I don't want a back button to occur past that view controller since a user shouldn't go back after a registration occurs. I have read on solutions that involve hiding the back button, but is that a part of best practices? Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

Comment: Hi! I have your same problem which is driving me crazy...have you found a solution maybe?

Comment: @Paulo I have tried to put your suggestion in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and so on but it doesn't work...why is this so hard to do?

Comment: @LoryLory are you using a tab bar controller?